# Defining a primary key: Customer numbers are unique only within a country but may be duplicated across different countries

Tags: database-design, primary-key, sqlite, candidate-key

I am facing the following problem:

I have a table with customer information like the *customer number*, i.e. `customerID` set up as the primary key, and, besides a number of other data, also a country value in the form of a *country code*, `countryID`.

However, customer data from other countries should also be imported into this table. Although the customer numbers are unique within a country, they are not cross-country. Customer numbers should not be changed for organizational reasons.

How can a key still be ensured for each customer in this table?

Answer (score 0):

I would use countryID, CustomerID as your unique key as you have stated that you will have a unique customer id for each country. I would start with countryID as that will be unique in the system and you can add in customerID in order to get a unique key for each customer.

Comment: Thank you very much,
that would have been about my idea, too. Since I'm not very familiar with sql, I don't really know how to implement it. Can someone please outline what statements I need in SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have a primary key consisting of multiple columns. This requires writing the constraint separately, as a table constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    countryID   INTEGER,
    customerID  INTEGER,
    [...],
    PRIMARY KEY (countryID, customerID)
);
```